# Getting the Selected Object in Select Option in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, javascript-objects, angular-services

I have this array of objects which I put on the select option and I would want to select one list of object in the select option. However I can't get the value of that list of object. It outputs [object] [Object]. I want to get that selected list of object of the corporation. I assigned it to the [value] and it gets [object][Object].

```
<div class="select" >
    <select class="form-control col-lg-8" #selectedValue (change)="assignCorporationToManage(selectedValue.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let corporation of user_corporations" [value]="corporation">{{corporation.corp_name}}</option>    
    </select>
</div>
```

> ts

```
assignCorporationToManage(selectedValue) {
     console.log(selectedValue)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this :

add ngModel for your select and use **ngModelChange** instead of change.

1. adding ngModel
2. using ngModelChange instead of change.
3. using [ngValue] instead of [value].

**component.html**

```
<select class="form-control col-lg-8" #selectedValue name="selectedValue" id="selectedValue" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="assignCorporationToManage($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let corporation of user_corporations" [ngValue]="corporation">{{corporation.corp_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Component.ts

```
assignCorporationToManage(selectedValue) {
     console.log(selectedValue)
}
```

Comment: change into this [(ngModel)]="selectedValue[i]"

Answer (score 0):

you can get that particular object from the list by using selectedValue.

```js
<select class="form-control col-lg-8" #selectedValue name="selectedValue" id="selectedValue" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <option *ngFor="let corporation of user_corporations" [ngValue]="corporation">{{corporation.corp_name}}</option>
</select>
```

in your ts or js file,

```js
const selectedObject = this.user_corporations.find((el: any) => {
  return el?.corporation == this.selectedValue;
});
```

After that, you can use the `selectedObject` whatever you want.